# Lazy loading in UITableView crashes app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, lazy-loading

I am using `UITableView` with `CustomCell`. `CustomCell` contains `UIImageView` and 2 `UILabel`.
In `UIImageView` I want to load image from **URL** and I want to save in my Document Directory.

Here is my code that I tried,

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[URLarr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];//arr is NSMutablearray of image URL

UIImage *img1 = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:savedImagePath];
if (!img1 || [UIImagePNGRepresentation(img1) length] <=0)
{
    id path =[URLarr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    path = [path stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
    NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:url, [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.row+1], nil ];

    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(loadImageInBackground:) withObject:arr];

}
```

and this one too.

```
//—————————————-lazy loading———————–
- (void)loadImageInBackground:(NSArray *)urlAndTagReference
{
        NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[urlAndTagReference objectAtIndex:0]];
        UIImage *imgload = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imgData];

        NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:imgload, [urlAndTagReference objectAtIndex:1], nil];

        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(assignImageToImageView:) withObject:arr waitUntilDone:YES];
}

- (void) assignImageToImageView:(NSArray *)imgAndTagReference
{
         NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
         NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
         NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[URLarr objectAtIndex:[[imgAndTagReference objectAtIndex:1] intValue]-1]];

         UIImage* imageToSave = savedImagePath;
         NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageToSave);
         [imageData writeToFile:savedImagePath atomically:NO];

}
```

Reason for crashing shows **NSInvalidArgumentException**. Also image is not showing in `UITableViewCell`. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do NSLog in - (void)loadImageInBackground:(NSArray *)urlAndTagReference and print [urlAndTagReference objectAtIndex:0]

Comment: Here's the google result for [Lazy Loading](http://tinyurl.com/bh2nahf) **I think you should better choose something already well developed framework for implementing this feature, something like [SDWebImageView](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)**.

Comment: @Durgaprasad: when i do Log it prints Image URL, like `http://www.abcd.com/image/image.png`

Answer (score 0):

For lazy loading of table view images there are few good options available. Can make use of them in your design to save time and avoid efforts to reinvent the wheel.
 
1. Apple lazy loading code --[link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Listings/Classes_RootViewController_m.html)

2. SDWebImage --[link](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

Cheers!
Amar.

Comment: I suggest you to give links in comment. If you know something about the issue stated, then provide an answer with good explanation with code.

Answer (score 0):

I think

`NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[urlAndTagReference objectAtIndex:0]];`

is not working. Instead try this

```
UIImage *imgload = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[urlAndTagReference objectAtIndex:0]]]
```

This may help. try this now.

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
[imageView_shake_image setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[urlAndTagReference objectAtIndex:0]]]];
UIImage *imgload = [imageView.image retain];
```

I am not sure. Just try

Comment: k it means still its not downloading